# Como integrar login do Facebook com Auth do ZF1?

Tags: php, facebook, zend, oauth

Tenho uma aplicação em ZF1 rodando e com sistema de autenticação que utiliza consulta em banco da dados. Gostaria de saber como posso integrar as 2 formas de logar, ou seja, se o usuário optar pelo facebook, ter os mesmos acessos e as mesmas informações daquele que optou por logar direto no site (user/senha).

Lembrando que não estou apenas procurando código pronto, minha dúvida é mais conceitual mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução que eu uso e recommendo é vincular o perfil do Facebook com o do seu site pelo endereço de email.

Você precisa integrar o processo de autorização com o OAuth do Facebook usando o escopo da API solicitado que include o valor 'email'.

Isso permitirá que você faça uma chamada à API do Facebook para este endereço abaixo para pedir o email do usuário.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me
```

Aí no seu aplicativo você verifica se já tem algum usuário com o email retornado. Se não existir, você cria um cadastro novo com os dados do usuário obtidos do Facebook.

Se já existir, você simplesmente inicia uma sessão de usuário logado para o usuário do seu site que tem o email retornado pelo Facebook.

Eu uso esse esquema em sites meus desde há uns 2 anos e os usuários adoraram, pois eu nunca peço usuário e senha. Os usuários odeiam ter de cadastrar uma nova senha e fazer o processo habitual de verificação do email. Assim com OAuth as duas coisas são evitadas.

Mesmo assim eu permito o cadastro habitual de usuário, senha e email para aqueles que não têm conta no Facebook ou não querem se logar pelo Facebook.

Aliás eu não apenas permito logar pelo Facebook, mas também pelo Google, Yahoo, Microsoft, StackOverflow e GitHub. A maior parte desses sites usa o esquema de OAuth. Alguns só fornecem email por OpenID.

Por isso eu desenvolvi uma classe genérica de [PHP para OAuth](http://www.phpclasses.org/oauth-api) que tem suporte integrado a dezenas de APIs, e pode suportar muitas mais com configuração manual.

Não é uma classe específica para Zend Framework, mas pode ser usada com qualquer framework incluindo Zend. Veja aqui o exemplo de como [logar no Facebook por OAuth](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/42010.html) usando esta classe.

Answer (score 0):

Se você possui dois sistemas de autenticação, o propósito deles é o mesmo: permitir que seu usuário tenha acesso ao sistema.

A autenticação via login é a mais comum, e que com um simples formulário (e as devidas validações de segurança) já resolve sua vida. Entretanto o login via Facebook é muito prático para o usuário, e dependendo das permissões que sua aplicação solicita, você pode ter as mesmas informaçṍes que teria caso optasse por um formulário de login convencional.

Quando o usuário permite que sua aplicação (ou site) tenha acesso aos seus dados por meio do Facebook, ele está permitindo que a aplicação tenha seu oauth_token e oauth_token_secret. Portanto, são esses valores que você terá de armazenar toda vez que tentar autorizar um usuário.

Quando um usuário, por exemplo, revoga o acesso de uma aplicação ao seu perfil, ele está invalidando o oauth_token e oauth_token_secret, de modo que sua aplicação terá de pedir permissão novamente para acessar seus dados. Por outro lado, o acesso ao usuário será negado, obrigando-o a fornecer seus dados novamente – ou fazer um cadastro tradicional.

Comment: Como já existe a autenticação via login (e pela possibilidade de parte do meu público alvo não querer utilizar o Facebook para este fim) será necessário que as duas formas de login caminhem juntas. Se entendi bem, para que o usuário possa logar novamente (pelo Facebook), a informação para autenticação será o oauth_token e oauth_token_secret? Seria então a inclusão dessas duas colunas na minha tabela de usuários?? Outra dúvida, nos docs do Facebook consta que posso recuperar o id através do metodo getuser(), e como faço para verificar o os tokens?